# "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" when using terminal

Tags: java, powershell, terminal

In my past computer science classes, we did all of our work inside Eclipse. Now, I am trying to compile and run java programs using the PowerShell. I am able to compile using javac, but when I try to run the class file with the main method I get the following error

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HW has been compiled by a more
>   recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this
>   version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to
>   52.0

The program I am trying to run to test this out is just a hello world program.

My versions of Java are Java 8 Update 251(64-bit) and Java SE Development Kit 12.0.2 (64-bit). Are these mismatched in any way or are there any other issues it could be?

Comment: The error message suggests that you must update your Java runtime - but doesn't the Development Kit come with its own runtime? Perhaps simply uninstalling the stand-alone runtime will solve your problem.

Comment: This solves my problem but the stand alone runtime is required for me to use other java apps as well as eclipse it would be better if I could do this without uninstalling Java 8.

Comment: Hmmm... https://www.java.com/en/download indicates that the runtime you have is the current one. Perhaps you can specify in the Development Kit when you compile your source code what runtime you want to support? (I'm not a Java user).

Comment: Have a look at chapter "Cross-Compilation Options" at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: If you find a working solution, I encourage you to post it as an answer and, after 48 hours, self-accept it.